# Sort <a> inside list item alphabatically

Tags: jquery

So i have a list:

```
<ul>
 <li><a>Belgium</a></li>
 <li><a>Florida</a></li>
 <li><a>Alaska</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to sort alphabatically so that it looks like:

- Alaska
- Belgium
- Florida

Please help with jquery only, i have seen some codes that allows this without the  tag, but i need this way, Thanks in advance.

Please see that there is  tag inside the list, so there is no duplicate

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please see that there is <a> tag inside the list, so there is no duplicate

Comment: @Subrata Still the same code if even though you have an `<a>` tag

Comment: he asked for a jQuery solution...

Comment: thanks eddie it solved my problem